# int in c/c++ of various size

Tags: c++, c

I have to send Data via UDP. For that I need to create a struct. according to that format in which I have to send data there is an int of 4bytes and another int of 2 bytes. how to I implement that in C/C++

Comment: There's no such thing as C/C++.

Comment: @Delan: but for this question there isn't any noticeable difference...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you want but.. does this work for you ?

```
struct data {
    uint32_t int4;
    uint16_t int2;
};
```

Comment: Guess there's also a header to include... maybe `stdint.h`?

Comment: For byte ordering and if you are on UNIX, you could use htons(), htonl(), ntohs() and ntohl().  See [here](http://books.google.fr/books?id=ptSC4LpwGA0C&pg=PA79&lpg=PA79&dq=Unix+to+network+short/long&source=bl&ots=Kr1zRieoPq&sig=GKf-cuvcxlg4cqGhZom5R4Nlugg&hl=fr&ei=BBA9TvbvNNCA-wbr6fCeBg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CDwQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q&f=false) for more info.

Comment: shouldn't he use pragma pack for aligning?

Answer (score 5):

The size of types such as `int`, `long`, and `long long` isn't strictly defined in C. If you want to specify integers of specific byte sizes, you should #include [stdint.h](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdint.h) and use `int32_t`, `uint16_t`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your 4 byte value will be an `unsigned long` and the 2 byte value will be an `unsigned short`.

Comment: `long`, `short`, etc. are unreliable if you want a specific width in bits. On my Linux x86_64 box, `unsigned long` is 64 bits wide.